# d3 problems. Circle image not appearing

Tags: d3.js

I am following this tutorial:

I have this code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var w = 500;
        var h = 100;

        var svg = d3.select("body")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", w)   // <-- Here
          .attr("height", h); // <-- and here!


        // var dataset = [];                                     //Initialize empty array
        // for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {                        //Loop 25 times
        //     var newNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 30);   //New random number (0-30)
        //     dataset.push(newNumber);                          //Add new number to array
        // }
        var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];

        svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter()
          .append("circle");

        var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter()
          .append("circle");

          circles.attr("cx", function(d, i) {
                  return (i * 50) + 25;
                })
                .attr("cy", h/2)
                .attr("r", function(d) {
                  return d;
                });
```

The SVG tag is showing up but there aren't any circles in the tag. What is going on? What am I missing? Currently it's just an empty SVG tag.

Comment: set up a JSFiddle and we can see whats up. May need to change the question, not a lot of people seem to like it haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get it working delete your first

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("circle");
```

```js
var w = 500;
        var h = 100;

        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w) // <-- Here
        .attr("height", h); // <-- and here!


        // var dataset = [];                                     //Initialize empty array
        // for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {                        //Loop 25 times
        //     var newNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 30);   //New random number (0-30)
        //     dataset.push(newNumber);                          //Add new number to array
        // }
        var dataset = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];

     //svg.selectAll("circle")
  //    .data(dataset)
  //    .enter()
  //    .append("circle");


        var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("circle");

        circles.attr("cx", function (d, i) {
            return (i * 50) + 25;
        })
            .attr("cy", h / 2)
            .attr("r", function (d) {
            return d;
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This first statement does in fact insert/append your circles using the `enter()` selection. They are present in the svg, but are empty since no attributes have been set. Furthermore, you are not keeping the references to them as you haven't assigned them to any variable.

The second statement uses an assignment to `var circles`. But, binding the same data and again refering to the `enter()` selection will yield an empty selection because no new data actually *entered*. Using this empty selection your attempts to set attributes like `cx`, `cy` and `r` are fruitless. Having deleted the first one, though, this statement now does exactly the job you are looking for.

Check one of the following articles for a more detailed view on using data joins with d3:

- [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218)
- [Thinking with joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)
- [How Selections Work](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/)

Comment: "But, binding the same data and again refering to the enter() selection will yield an empty selection because no new data actually entered." I think this is the key sentence. Can you explain this further? I didn't even notice my duplicate code until now.

Comment: That's a vast field, yet essential to how d3 works. Try reading the articles I have linked to. They cover every detail of it. If you have any questions afterwards feel free to ask again.